# How to hide an element on a specific page using uBlock Origin (or AdBlock / Plus)?

Tags: adblock, ublock, ublock-origin

I know I can block a particular element on a whole site with a rule like:

```
example.com##.blockedClass
```

Is there a way to do have particular elements *only blocked on particular pages*?  I note that

```
example.com/path/*##.blockedClass
```

does not have the desired result (it seems to do nothing).

Comment: I asked the same question here: https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=57119&p=177214#p177214 Greasemonkey addon could do it with JavaScript but an easier solution would be better.

Answer (score 5):

This is done by adding `:matches-path` to your rule, e.g.:

```
example.com##tr:has-text(/done/):matches-path(sub/page)
```

This will block all **tr** on example.com/sub/page which contain the text 'done'.